# Checking if any item in the array is equal to this value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, rxjs

This function logs the user as having read the page and gets triggered when the user clicks on to the next page.

It firsts subscribes to the database and retrieves a list of all the pages that the user has read..

My goal is to only log the pages that the user has not read e.g. not in the database.

This function will not log the page as being read if the list returned from the database contains the same page number as the page that was just read.

However this only works on the first click and then if I go back to the same page again and click next it will log the page number into the database...

Any suggestions on how to fix this bug, need another eye over this code I know its something simple.. Cheers!

```
logAsWatched() {
let uid = this.windowRef.nativeWindow.firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
this.projectId = this.uidpage.project.id;
this.subscription = this.af.database.list(`pagelogs/${uid}/${this.projectId}`).subscribe(
  data => {
    console.dir(data);
    if (data.length >= 1) {
      let pagelogArray = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        let pageNumber = data[i];
        pagelogArray.push(pageNumber);
      }
      console.log('pagelogArray', pagelogArray);
      console.log('page order', this.pageOrder);

      let newArray = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < pagelogArray.length; ++i) {
        newArray.push(pagelogArray[i].pNumber);
      }
      console.log(`newArray : ${newArray}`);
      if (!newArray.indexOf(this.pageOrder)) {
        console.log('page has allready been logged');
      } else {
        console.log('logging this page as watched');
        this.setLogAsWatchedData();
      }
    } else {
      console.log('No page logs have been added');
      this.setLogAsWatchedData();
    }
  }, (error) => { console.log(`page log error: ${error}`); }
);
```

}

```
  setLogAsWatchedData() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    let uid = this.windowRef.nativeWindow.firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    this.windowRef.nativeWindow
      .firebase.database().
      ref(`pagelogs/${uid}/${this.projectId}`)
      .push().set({ pNumber: this.pageOrder });

  }
```

Comment: You incorrectly check for page been logged: `if (!newArray.indexOf(this.pageOrder))`. It should be `if (newArray.indexOf(this.pageOrder) !== -1)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can look into how to use Filter [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter] , to out pages that are logged as read vs not read.

Comment: Thanks for that @Ryan Basmajian ! However the the bug is still in the code. 
its strange because there is only 2 points where the data will be sent to the server, which is at the end of the two if else statements below the console.log's.

` } else {
        console.log('logging this page as watched');
        this.setLogAsWatchedData();
      }
    } else {
      console.log('No page logs have been added');
      this.setLogAsWatchedData(); `

 The strange this is when the page gets logged the second time the console.log does not show up on the console...

Comment: Ended up refactoring the code to use a promise to return the data instead of subscribing to it. This has fixed the problem of the data getting logged a second time. Cheers!